# How to Edit Duration Unit label in Infragistics XamGantt?

Tags: wpf, infragistics, gantt-chart

I use XamGantt in WPF.

i have to use ElapsedSeconds for ProjectDurationFormat but i don't want to see the unit label in GridView.

for example

**1000 esecs  => 1000**

how can i do?

I tried to modify DurationText property But It affects the TaskBar. (I think it has the correct format.)